Request for an analysis of TV show (Taskmaster) 100th episode balloon-popping task
Watching the 100th episode of a British comedy panel show called Taskmaster, I found the final task (36:00-42:50 if you want to watch it for entertainment or clarification) highly interesting from a mathematical perspective. In case you don’t want to click the link, I’ve laid out the rules as clearly as possible here based on what occurred in the episode:
Before five contestants are $100$ indistinguishable balloons, five of which are secretly designated “bad” balloons. The contestants loop through the following procedure:

Contestant 1 sequentially (so all at different times) pops some number from $1$ to $10$ inclusive of balloons (they choose whether to continue after each balloon), at which point their turn is over. If at any point during their turn a bad balloon is popped, Contestant 1 is eliminated and their turn is over. A bad balloon does not count as a popped balloon.
Contestants 2-5 do the same.
Any non-eliminated contestants go through the same procedure as many times as it takes to eliminate four contestants.
Exactly when four bad balloons have been popped, the game is over.

At the end, points are given out as follows: $10$ points to the non-eliminated contestant, then $4-3-2-1$ points to the other contestants by decreasing total number of balloons popped (assume ties are broken at random because I want to maintain $4-3-2-1$, even though this is likely not what would have occurred in the original game).
For example, as occurred in the episode (though note that the contestants are not playing optimally):

Contestant 1 pops $4$ balloons ($4-0-0-0-0$)
Contestant 2 pops $3$ balloons and then a bad balloon ($4-3^*-0-0-0$)
Contestant 3 pops $7$ balloons ($4-3^*-7-0-0$)
Contestant 4 pops $8$ balloons ($4-3^*-7-8-0$)
Contestant 5 pops $4$ balloons ($4-3^*-7-8-4$)
Contestant 1 pops a bad balloon ($4^*-3^*-7-8-4$)
Contestant 3 pops $8$ balloons ($4^*-3^*-15-8-4$)
Contestant 4 pops $6$ balloons ($4^*-3^*-15-14-4$)
Contestant 5 pops $5$ balloons ($4^*-3^*-15-14-9$)
Contestant 3 pops $6$ balloons and then a bad balloon ($4^*-3^*-21^*-14-9$)
Contestant 4 pops $6$ balloons ($4^*-3^*-21^*-20-9$)
Contestant 5 pops $2$ balloons ($4^*-3^*-21^*-20-11$)
Contestant 4 pops $2$ balloons ($4^*-3^*-21^*-22-11$)
Contestant 5 pops $3$ balloons and then a bad balloon ($4^*-3^*-21^*-22-14^*$)

The points would then be as follows: $10$ points to Contestant 4, $4$ points to Contestant 3, $3$ points to Contestant 5, $2$ points to Contestant 1, and $1$ point to Contestant 2. (Note: somehow in the actual episode the scores for Contestants 3 and 4 wound up at $26$ each. I assume another round occurred at some point that was cut out of/into the rest of the footage (namely most likely somewhere in parts 10 and 11 based on the way the scores shown change) in order to flow better. That’s not strictly relevant mathematically, as the contestants were not playing optimally and this is just an example game anyway, but I did want to explain any possible confusion between the episode’s scores and mine for anyone who did check the link.)
So my questions are:

If each contestant plays so as to maximize their expected points (and each contestant knows that every other contestant will do the same and every contestant knows that etc.):

What does the expected distribution of points look like by contestant?
What is the expected distribution of popped balloons by contestant?
What is the probability each contestant will win?
How many balloons should Contestant 1 attempt to pop on the first turn?


For example, it seems to me that at least in steps 12-14, Contestants 4 and 5 are not playing so as to maximize their expected points. Both, as best I can tell, should be only popping one balloon on each turn in order to minimize their odds of popping a bad balloon: Contestant 4 should be aiming for the jump to ten points instead of aiming for only a 1-point increase in trying to overtake Contestant 3, and Contestant 5 should be doing the same instead of trying to overtake Contestants 3 and 4 and their large leads. I think an easy, good strategy is to just pop one balloon at a time in order to gun hard for the ten points for not being eliminated even at the cost of having very few points if you do happen to be eliminated, but I’d hope the optimal strategy is a bit more interesting than just “avoid all risks”.
I did see this MSE question, which in many ways looks so similar to mine I suspect they also got the idea from Taskmaster, but it's not equivalent mathematically because the way the points are distributed is not equivalent- their method appears to be just "you win if you [pop] the most [balloons]", which is very different than the one laid out in this question.
Solutions for any of the four questions I asked would be gratefully appreciated, though I would certainly be more inclined to accept an answer that solved two or three or four of them. Thank you!

Also, I’d like to take this opportunity to recommend Taskmaster in general- it’s consistently absolutely hilarious, and you don’t really need any background to jump in at any point beyond potentially not understanding a few in-jokes if you don’t go in order. I personally suggest Series 5, 7, 11, 12, 14, and 16, though you can't really go wrong and Series 18 is currently ongoing. If you do watch/enjoy it, thank me later. :)

How is the number determined?  Does each contestant just stop when they feel like it (after they have popped $4$) or is the number imposed on them somehow?

They choose when to stop. I just now clarified in the question body.

My instinct would be to stick to $1$ each shot, as the value of survival far exceeds the difference between $1$ and $4$ points.   Not sure I am right about that, but it might be worth while simulating that one against other strategies.

That was my first thought too, but it really seems a shame to me if that was to be optimal. If that were the case, though, I imagine an interesting follow-up question could be something along the lines of "at how many points for being the last person not eliminated does some other strategy surpass the 'always pop only one' strategy?"

As I say, I am not sure I am right.  After all, $4$ people will be eliminated and an optimal strategy will only help you so much with that.  Maybe it's better to take a little risk in the hopes of building up some credit before elimination.    I'd simulate it.  Say everybody plays it safe, but one contestant does $2$ at a time or whatever.  How does that play out?  I'd definitely run some simulations before attempting it analytically.

My guess would be that a dwindling strategy - popping fewer balloons as the likelyhood of a bad one increases - would be more successful, but likely the difference would be small, taking many simulations to be felt. Also, the best strategy for player 5 is likely to be different from the best strategy for player 1.
